# how can i know that a stack is empty if i use this method to pop elements?

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack in C using singly linked lists, it all works fine as long as the stack is non-empty. Once empty my pop method never detects that its empty but gives some random values. Is there any way so that i can know the stack is empty ? Here is the pop method i'm using along with a sample main program output.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node* top;
    push(&top,5);
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));

    return 0;
}

int pop(Node** top)
{
    if(*top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    int temp = (*top)->iData;
    *top = (*top)->next;
    return temp;
}
```

output:

```
Popped Element: 5
Popped Element: 1707388
```

EDIT: 
here is the code for push

```
void push(Node** top ,int num)
{
    Node* temp = (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->iData = num;
    temp->next = *top;
    *top = temp;
}
```

Comment: can u show your push() code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize next to NULL while creating and adding a new node to the list. and use

```
return -1;
```

instead of

```
return;
```

Edit:

Initialize *top =NULL in main like

```
   int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node* top=NULL;
    push(&top,5);
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `pop` function needs to return an integer. So this snippet of code

```
if(*top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
```

needs to be amended.

Either get `pop` to take a pointer to an integer that will have the value and the `pop` function returns true if that is the case - or have a have that should not be on the stack e.g. -1.

So make the `return` read `return(-1);`

or

```
int pop(Node** top, int *value)
{
    if(*top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    *value = (*top)->iData;
    *top = (*top)->next;
    return 1;
}
```

**EDIT**

After changing `Node *top = NULL` the following code for `push`

```
void push(Node **top, int value)
{
    Node *newTop = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newTop->next = *top;
    *top = newTop;
    newTop->iData = value;
}
```

Comment: i have tried returning -1, however the *top==NULL condition is never met as it always contained some junk values even though the stack is empty. so is there any way to detect that we've reached end of the stack ? i need the function prototype like pop(&top) with int as return value so i was wondering if detecting an empty stack is possible using my method.

Comment: Forgot to mention the line `Node* top;` should read `Node* top = NULL;` You need to post the code for `push` for further comment.

Comment: Initializing *top to NULL in main solved the problem ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

initialize next to NULL inside the Ctor of Node.
And return a value (-1 as example) if the stack is empty

**Edit:**

If you not have a Ctor. (You use malloc)
Then you have to initialize the next field of the first node on the stack to NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from your node declaration, if you declare a Node*, you have to allocate it before using it. test this maybe (i don t have any compiler on this computer so i cannot test it by myself)

```
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node* top;
    top = malloc(sizeof(*top));
    push(&top,5);
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));

    return 0;
}

int pop(Node** top)
{
    if(*top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    int temp = (*top)->iData;
    *top = (*top)->next;
    return temp;
}
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: it worked for one run but further invocations of pop gave junk values again the out put was something like this :
`
Popped Element: 5
Popped Element: 0
Error: Stack is empty!
Popped Element: -1 `

Comment: It's good ? If not i think you should free the linkedlist after the 2 printf.

Comment: Since my push method allocates the space i didn't allocate the space for top in main as you have suggested. Instead initializing the *top to NULL solved the problem ! :)

Comment: Good luck for your soft then !

Answer (score 0):

Define a global or static variable to memorize your usage of the stack. Every time you push some thing in the stack, adjust the value of you counter with SizeOf(...) and the inverse for pop.

Answer (score 0):

while creating node i.e in push(), If first(Head) element's next should be NULL.

In your case, `(*top)->next` is not NULL.

so

```
printf("Error: Stack is empty!\n");
return;
```

not executed.

**For Edit:**

```
void push(Node** top ,int num)
{

    Node* temp = (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));

     if(*top == NULL)
     {
         temp->next = NULL;
     }
     else
     {
         temp->next = *top;
     }
    temp->iData = num;    
    *top = temp;
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
int iData;
struct Node *next;
}Node;

int pop(Node** top)
{
    if(*top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    Node *tmp = *top;
    int temp = tmp->iData;
    *top = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);
    return temp;
}

void push(Node** top ,int num)
{

    Node* temp = (Node* )malloc(sizeof(Node));

     if(*top == NULL)
     {
         temp->next = NULL;
     }
     else
     {
         temp->next = *top;
     }
    temp->iData = num;
    *top = temp;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node* top;
    push(&top,5);
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));
    printf("Popped Element: %d\n",pop(&top));

    return 0;
}
```

This will prints

```
Popped Element: 5
Error: Stack is empty!
Popped Element: 0
```

Second `Popped Element: 0` is because of calling pop() twice. anyway Stack Empty is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You may just return the Node and not the integer, if the node is `NULL`, the list is empty, else you may get the node data :

```
Node *pop (Node **top)
{
    Node *ret = NULL;

    if (*top != NULL)
    {
        ret = *top;
        *top = (*top)->next;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: yes i could return the Node* and get data but the function prototype needs to be as int pop(Node** top [,int *num])